# Query optimizing suggession needed

Tags: sql-server-2008, query-optimization

I have written a script which takes about 15 hours to execute. I need some query optimization technique or suggestion to make this script as faster as possible...
If anyone could help, take a look on the script:

```
declare @max_date date
declare @client_bp_id int

Select @max_date=MAX(tran_date) from All_Share_Txn

DELETE FROM Client_Share_Balance

DECLARE All_Client_Bp_Id CURSOR FOR
SELECT Bp_id FROM  Client       --Take All Client's BPID 
    OPEN All_Client_Bp_Id
    FETCH NEXT FROM All_Client_Bp_Id
        INTO @client_bp_id
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

    Insert Client_Share_Balance(Bp_id,Instrument_Id,Quantity_Total,Quantity_Matured,Quantity_Pledge,AVG_Cost,Updated_At,Created_At,Company_Id,Created_By,Updated_By)
    select @client_bp_id,Instrument_Id,
       sum(case when Is_buy='True' then Quantity when Is_buy='False'  then -quantity end), --as Total Quantity
       sum(case when Mature_Date_Share <= @max_date then (case Is_buy when '1' then quantity when '0' then -quantity end) else 0 end),  --as Free Qty
       ISnull((select sum(case pu.IsBuy when '1' then -pu.quantity else pu.quantity end) from
            (Select * from Pledge UNION Select * from Unpledge) pu
                where pu.Client_Bp_id=@client_bp_id and pu.Instrument_Id=t1.Instrument_Id and pu.Txn_Date<=@max_date
                group by pu.Client_Bp_id,pu.Instrument_Id),0),  -- as Pledge_Quantity
       dbo.Avg_Cost(@client_bp_id,Instrument_Id), --as Avg_rate
       GETDATE(),GETDATE(),309,1,1

    from All_Share_Txn t1
    where Client_Bp_id=@client_bp_id and Instrument_Id is not null 
    group by Instrument_Id
    having sum(case Is_buy when '1' then quantity when '0' then -quantity end)<> 0
    or sum(case when Mature_Date_Share <= @max_date then (case Is_buy when '1' then quantity when '0' then -quantity end) else 0 end) <> 0

    FETCH NEXT FROM All_Client_Bp_Id
        INTO @client_bp_id

END

CLOSE All_Client_Bp_Id
DEALLOCATE All_Client_Bp_Id
```

Just need to verify if the code could be written more efficiently..

Comment: Explore rewriting this without a cursor. That should improve performance a lot.

Comment: @AbdurRahman- Did you try [**this answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10606894/1379794)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Replace * with you ColumnNames **`Select * from Pledge`**. It should be like
   **`Select Instrument_Id from Pledge`**
2. Exclude the usage of Cursor.
3. Do you have unique records in `Pledge` and `Unpledge` table, if so, `UNION ALL` should be used. As it is faster comparing with `UNION`
4. Insert the records of `All_Share_Txn` in `Local Temporary Table`.
5. Create another `Local Temporary table` which will have fields 'Total Quantity' information based upon Instrument_Id column and `Instrument_Id`. Now evaluate the Switch case based condition and insert the records for Quantity Information in this table. Please note while you extract information for this context, use the Local Temporary  Table as created in Step 3.
6. Create another `Local Temporary table` which will have fields 'Free Qty' information based upon Instrument_Id column and `Instrument_Id`. Now evaluate the Switch case based condition and insert the records for `Free Qty` Information in this table.  Please note while you extract information for this context, use the Local Temporary  Table as created in Step 3.
7. Create another `Local Temporary table` which will have fields 'Pledge_Quantity'  information based upon Instrument_Id column and `Instrument_Id`. Now evaluate the Switch case based condition and insert the records 
   for `Pledge_Quantity` Information in this table.  Please note while you extract information for this context, use the Local Temporary  Table as created in Step 3.
8. Create another `Local Temporary table` which will have fields 'Avg_rate'  information based upon Instrument_Id column and `Instrument_Id`. Now evaluate the Switch case based condition and insert the records 
   for `Avg_rate` Information in this table.  Please note while you extract information for this context, use the Local Temporary  Table as created in Step 3.
9. Now, with the help of Joins among the tables created in Step 3, 4, 5, 6, 7. You can instantly get the Resultset.

Comment: too many temporary tables.. does it requires such too many tables..?? anyway +1 for your answer..

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you code. The cursor is the bottleneck in your code. So I would skip the cursor and do something like this:

```
Insert Client_Share_Balance(Bp_id,Instrument_Id..)
select Client_Bp_id,
......
from All_Share_Txn t1
where EXISTS(SELECT NULL FROM Client WHERE Client_Bp_id=t1.Bp_id) 
and Instrument_Id is not null 
group by Instrument_Id,Client_Bp_id
.......
```

Comment: Thank you.. It seems more convenient.. I am trying to implement my code as like you suggested.. if it improves performance i'll accept your answer.. Thanks again.. +1 for your answer..

Comment: it improves performance.. now the query takes 5 hours to execute.. But i think it could be more faster.. if have any other suggestion.. please give me..

Answer (score 0):

Unless you care that you are reading COMMITTED data, then you can tell SQL Server to look at data the way it is, without holding any locks on the objects... basically the same behavior as WITH (NOLOCK), but Microsoft recommends not using object hints and letting SQL Server decide on the best locking method to use.  Without "worrying" about data being committed or not, this greatly speeds up fetching data.

Add this to the top of your query

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED 
--Set at the connection level, not a one time thing
GO

[See this link TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx)

Next thing, please check that your unique id columns having Clustered Indexes on them.  If they just have unique constraints, that still leaves you with a heap and not a table.  Heaps are basically a scattered mess.  (You probably know this stuff, just mentioning it)  Next, make sure you have non-clustered indexes for all of the columns you use in WHERE ORDER  BY GROUP HAVING... and include columns that are returned frequently; this consumes more disk space btw.  Use compressed indexes and tables if you are using Enterprise Version or higher.

I would run UPDATE STATISTICS WITH FULLSCAN on the tables to give SQL Server the latest and greatest statistics.  Rebuilding the clustered index will do this for you by the way, and also you can tell update only data statistics to help speed this process up, since it can take while if your tables are millions of rows.

The biggest performance hit you are taking is the fact that you are grouping on aggregated results.  SQL Server is going to scanning, using work tables, sorting...everything BUT seeking indexes, all because there is no index to be used to help your GROUP BY, HAVING, etc..

Sometimes we have no choice in this matter, but there are tricks like creating a #temporary table (or table object, and yes, you can create indexes on both) and populating it with pre calculated results, making sure that this #temporary table can be joined on.  When you use ORDER BY, GROUP BY, HAVING , unless you are using a column, or multiple columns and use aggregates like SUM or scalar value user-defined functions, it's going to be slow - depending on what you define as slow :) but you did state that you think it should be faster.

Some basic settings to look at for any instance of SQL Server:

1. tempdb should have the same number of files as you have cores, all the same size and all the same growth rate using MB, not %.  I would only go up to 8 files if you have more than 8 cores.  Restart the instance after making changes; you do HAVE TO but I recommend it.

   Example:  12 cores.

   ```
   tempdb.mdf      size= 1024MB   growby= 256MB
   tempdb2.ndf  size= 1024MB   growby= 256MB
   (etc)
   tempdb8.ndf size= 1024MB   growby= 256MB
   ```
2. Same with your database.  If you need to add more files, then do so with the recommended size settings and rebuild all of your clustered indexes, this will spread the data across the files, since it will be rebuilding the physical structure of the data.
3. Don't let SQL Server take up all the memory! Set its limit to total_avail_phys_memory minus 2GB (leave the O/S a good amount memory)
4. Don't just use the PRIMARY FILE GROUP; separate your data and your indexes in to their own file groups.  If you can, put the indexes on their on RAID 10 drives and data on RAID 5 or 6.
5. Make sure you're giving SQL Server user databases the care they need with scheduled maintenance with a maintenance plan or by roll your own scripts.
6. Data on RAID 5, Logs on RAID 10, Tempdb on RAID 10 - each LUN (drive letter) should have dedicated spindles (drives)

I hope these suggestions are helpful, if anything they should be helpful for the overall performance of the instance.